# C#: Creating a new FileInfo in a directory that you have the DirectoryInfo of

Tags: c#, file, directory

I was just wondering when you have for example:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp");
```

Is there an easier/clearer way to add a new file to that directory than this?

```
var file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dir.FullName, "file.ext"));
```

I'm thinking I can probably just make an extension method or something, but curious if something already exists that can't see here... I mean the `DirectoryInfo` does have `GetFiles()` method for example.

Comment: The code in your question looks about right to me (marked as wiki as I'm not really adding value here...)

Comment: yeah, it's missing a `(DirectoryInfo, string)` constructor

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What is it that you want to do? The title says "Creating a new file". A FileInfo object is not a file; it's an object holding information about a file (that may or may not exist). If you actually want to *create* the file, there are a number of ways of doing so. One of the simplest ways would be this:

```
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dir.FullName, "file.ext"), "some text");
```

If you want to create the file based on the `FileInfo` object instead, you can use the following approach:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp");
var file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dir.FullName, "file.ext"));
if (!file.Exists) // you may not want to overwrite existing files
{
    using (Stream stream = file.OpenWrite())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write("some text");
    }
}
```

As a side note: it is `dir.FullName`, not `dir.FullPath`.

Comment: oh, good call. FullPath was protected field. FullName is the property. Just scanned the MSDN member page a bit too fast :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use:

```
File.Create(@"C:\Temp\file.ext");
```

or

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp");
File.Create(dir.FullName + "\\file.ext");
```

Comment: Because I have the DirectoryInfo and a file name. Not both together.

Answer (score 1):

While there does exist `Directorynfo.GetFiles()` methods, they only return files that actually exist on disk. `Path.Combine` is about hypothetical paths.

Try these extension methods:

```
    public static FileInfo CombineWithFileName(this DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, string fileName)
    {
        return new FileInfo(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.Name, fileName));
    }

    public static DirectoryInfo CombineWithDirectoryName(this DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, string directoryName)
    {
        return new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.Name, directoryName));
    }
```

Comment: I was always disappointed that the .NET framework didn't go further to encapsulate paths in a rich type. They could have skipped `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo`, made `Path` an instance type, and we would have a lot of type safety where today we only have strings.