# New file in folder

Tags: c#, file, detect

I want to detect when a new file is added to a existing folder and access it.

How can I do this (C#)?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078116/c-creating-a-new-file-in-a-directory-that-you-have-the-directoryinfo-of

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx?ppud=4)

1. [Tutorial 1](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-using-the-filesystemwatcher-class)
2. [Tutorial 2](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial173_File-monitoring-using-FileSystemWatcher.html)

Comment: Don't forget that this method is not a 100% reliable in all circumstances (read the remarks section in MSDN). For a fail-safe implementation there is no way around (additional) polling.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx), this is the class you might want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [FileSystemWatcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use the FileSystemWatcher class wich raises events when a file is created, updated etc.

[FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Windows dude, but generally speaking, find out if there is a Windows API call which allows you to watch a directory.